# React script tags usage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have a guestion about, how to insert script tags in my React app, scripts below

```
<script>
    nipGoRODO="9571112889";
    GoRODOcertWidth="200";
    GoRODOcertOrientation="vertical";
    GoRODOcertText=1;
    GoRODOcertTextColor="000000";
</script>
<script src="https://www.gorodo.pl/moj_certyfikat_rodo.js"></script>
```

I have tried past it between  tags and inside  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: }} in div element but still nothing apears in browser.

Comment: Do you use React cdn links or React local environment?

Comment: Can't you just add them to your `public/index.html` file?  I'm pretty sure that is where I have added Script tags in my React apps.

Comment: @DineshMsd Reat cdn links

Comment: @dmikester1 it should apear as div, so I cant past it in index.html

Comment: Follow these from w3schools this might help you

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp